# Exporting Images from Vincent in ipython

Tags: python, json, output, choropleth, vincent

I've been using vincent in python to make choropleth maps, now i'd like to make them into images to use for a presentation. Does anyone know how to do this?
Below is the code I'm using:

```
county_borders = r'us_counties.topo.json'
geo_data = [{'name': 'counties',
         'url': county_borders,
         'feature': 'us_counties.geo'}]
choro_pop = vincent.Map(data=counties_only, geo_data=geo_data, scale=1500, projection='albersUsa',
      data_bind='CENSUS2010POP', data_key='FIPS',
      map_key={'counties': 'properties.FIPS'})
choro_pop.marks[0].properties.enter.stroke_opacity = ValueRef(value=0.5)
choro_pop.rebind(column = 'ESTIMATESBASE2010', brew = 'OrRd')
choro_pop.to_json('Counties_Population_choropleth.json', html_out=True, html_path='Counties_Population_choropleth.html')
choro_pop.display()
```

This gives me a map in the ipython notebook (yay!) and outputs both an html file and a .json file. The html file is just a "scaffold" it doesn't actually contain any data that I can tell, and it doesn't display anything when opened in a browser (I've tried chrome).

The .json file I know is dictionary-like, but I'm not sure how to use it to draw a nice image.

thanks!

edit1: This is what's in the html file

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Vega Scaffold</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.geo.projection.v0.min.js" charset="utf-8">    </script>
    <script src="http://trifacta.github.com/vega/vega.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="vis"></div>
  </body>
<script type="text/javascript">
// parse a spec and create a visualization view
function parse(spec) {
  vg.parse.spec(spec, function(chart) { chart({el:"#vis"}).update(); });
}
parse("Counties_Population_change_choropleth.json");
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: If the html file generated has the image, then it has to be saved as image somewhere on you system. Or is the HTML file just a table? And please include an example image of the type of images you want to generate.

Comment: The most simple, but manual, solution would be to take a screenshot - This will give you an image, static by definition.  If you need an exported html file, with the dynamic features, try the `bar.to_json('bar.json', html_out=True, html_path='bar_template.html')` approach. See http://vincent.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#output . To automatically generate images, you should probably need a headless browser or maybe exploit the little used vincent-qt package.

Comment: Will exporting from ipython be good enough? Some JS could allow you to export vincent drawn to a canvas as png.

Comment: @jcoppens The html file is a "scaffold" my understanding is that it has the potential to parse the .json file somehow? But when I load it up it just gives me a blank page.

Comment: @udi I considered the screenshot option :D All I really need is the static image, I was hoping for better resolution than a screenshot though. I guess part of my issue is that I don't really understand how to handle a .json file at all.

Exporting it from ipython would be perfect! Is "canvas" another package?

Comment: @prion It might be interesting to see the code of the HTML file. If it isn't too long, paste the file in your original question. We might be able to learn something from it. Or maybe you could use a small dataset and post the .JSON file?

Comment: @jcoppens edited to include html file code

Comment: Thanks. I had downloaded the package yesterday - I'm always interested in graphics toolboxes :) As you can see, there is a call to the javascript parse() function, which should be available from http://trifacta.github.io/vega/vega.js  I also downloaded that script, but (IMO) it looks a little messy - very few comments. I have to leave for work now, but if I have some time, I'll look again when I come back. Do you have a screenshot on what you are trying to obtain?